# svn group members is too long and messy

Tags: svn

file=`/svn_repository/conf/authz`

One of the group is too long and messy and it's hard to organize.

```
dev_group=antonio.rudiger,marcos.alonso,andreas.christensen,thiago.silva,trevoh.chalogbah,ben.chilwelll,kenedy.john,reece.james,cesar.azpilicueta,malang.sarr...jorginho
```

I'm going to try below method but I'm not sure if it works

```
senior_group=antonio.rudiger,reece.james
junior_group=marcos.alonso,cesar.azpilicueta
dev_group=${senoir_group}","${junior_group}",andreas.christensen"
```

Is this going to work? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm going to try below method but I'm not sure if it works

It *will work* as soon as you'll use the right syntax (according to old, but still correct [SVN Book note](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html#svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.groups)) for "groups inside groups"

> Groups can also be defined to contain other groups:
>
> ```
> [groups]
> calc-developers = harry, sally, joe
> paint-developers = frank, sally, jane
> everyone = @calc-developers, @paint-developers
> ```